# Compute correlation for individual observations that fulfill some critera

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame in R that looks like this

```
structure(list(Period = structure(c(2021.33333333333, 2021.41666666667, 
2021.5, 2021.58333333333, 2021.66666666667, 2021.75, 2021.83333333333, 
2021.91666666667, 2022, 2021.33333333333, 2021.41666666667, 2021.5, 
2021.58333333333, 2021.66666666667, 2021.75, 2021.83333333333, 
2021.91666666667, 2022, 2021.33333333333, 2021.41666666667), class = "yearmon"), 
    `Bransch (SNI 2007)` = c("Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", 
    "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", 
    "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", 
    "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", 
    "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", "Livsmedelsindustri (SNI 10-12)", 
    "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", 
    "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", 
    "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", 
    "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", 
    "Textilindustri (SNI 13-15)", "Trävaruindustri (SNI 16)", 
    "Trävaruindustri (SNI 16)"), outcome = c(19, 19, 38, 19, 
    14, 39, 40, 29, 48, 32, 39, 44, 7, 0, 2, 22, 1, -26, 38, 
    37), expectations = c(41, 39, 33, 28, 21, 38, 15, 27, 14, 
    35, 36, 36, 53, 41, 24, 36, 11, 54, 32, 33), predict = c(-4, 
    -4, -6, -9, -10, 9, -18, -7, -28, 9, 8, -1, 19, -10, 17, 
    -3, -5, 2, 2, -2), corr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

where I want to compute the correlation between the outcome and predict as well as expectations and predict column. I I want to do this per month, i.e. I have tried the following code

```
ifelse(data$Period == 'maj 2021', cor(data$outcome, data$predict), NA)
```

but that line computes the correlation of the whole sample and save it in the cells where the Period column equals may 2021. But I want to compute the correlation for all the observations in may 2021 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the month of may

```r
cor(data$outcome[data$Period == 'maj 2021'], data$predict[data$Period == 'maj 2021'])
```